# fprintd-enroll list_devices failed: No devices available

Tags: kali-linux, drivers, hp, fingerprint

Hey I'm using Hp folio 9470m but fprintd is not detecting my fingerprint reader. This is the model of my fingerprint sensor Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS491. Guys can anyone help me

Answer (score 4):

Sorry, Validity VFS491 is not on [fprintd's list of supported devices.](https://fprint.freedesktop.org/supported-devices.html)

[Here seems to be a separate project that uses the proprietary driver components provided by Validity Sensors, Inc.](https://github.com/rindeal/libfprint-vfs_proprietary-driver) but unfortunately it looks like [the development is halted because libfprint is not really suitable for plugging in proprietary drivers.](https://github.com/rindeal/libfprint-vfs_proprietary-driver/issues/8)

Comment: Is there any tool which will work for Validity VFS491?